# How get Callable from future result

Tags: java, multithreading

I ping services nodes and check if it is alive or not. My class, which ping all services is below:

```
   public abstract class PingCallable implements Callable<ResponseEntity<String>> {


    @Override
    public ResponseEntity call() throws Exception {

        try {

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("", headers);

            return restTemplate.exchange(new URI(getPingUrl()), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity("Exception occured while ping. Exception message = " + ExceptionUtil.getFullCauseMessage(ex), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

        }
    }

    protected abstract String getPingUrl();

}

public class ServicePingCallable extends PingCallable {

    private Node node;

    public ServicePingCallable(Node node) {
        this.node = node;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPingUrl() {
        return "//" + node.getIp() + "/api/" + node.getService().getServicePath() + "/pingService";
    }

   public Node getNode(){
        return this.node;
   }

}
```

Method which pings service nodes is here:

```
 @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${config.ping.fixedDelay}")
public void pingServices() throws InterruptedException {

    List<Node> nodeList = serviceRepository.findAll();

    List<ServicePingCallable> callableList = new ArrayList<>(nodeList.size());

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    try {


        for (Node node : nodeList) {
            ServicePingCallable pingCallable = new ServicePingCallable(node);
            callableList.add(pingCallable);
        }

        List<Future<ResponseEntity<String>>> responses = executor.invokeAll(callableList, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                      for(Future<ResponseEntity<String>> response: responses){

              // here I should check response HttpStatus and response text and save node ping state.
// But how I can know here for which Node is response?    
//It whould be great to have such method: 
//ServicePingCallable  callable = (ServicePingCallable)response.getCallable();
//Node = callable.getNode();


            }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       //catch and log here
    } finally {
        if (!executor.isShutdown()) {
            try {
                executor.shutdown();
            } catch (Exception ex1) {
            }
        }
    }
```

I can add to `PingCallable` private filed `ResponseEntity` and return from `call()` the `PingCallable` but this approach is like workaround and not clear.
I think this is common task and should be some pattern how to get the callable from the future result. If you know it please share.

Comment: Are you unable to extract the `ResponseEntity` with `future.get()` and then extract the information you need from what I assume is Spring's  `ResponseEntity` via `entity.getBody().getWhatYouNeedHere()`?

Comment: I can do as you desribed, but the body of response entity does not contain information about node. It just have message, that node works fine or message with error.